# how to add new rows and add new datas in that added new rows and pass those values to server in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying this for add new rows and send the newly added rowdata to server.
my requirement is I need to add new rows by clicking ADD Rows button, after added empty row with edit and delete button.i have to add mac adddress in empty row by using edit button after edit i need to save and  pass this value along with rowdata(already having some data) to server

table.component.html

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md rounded-pill" (click)="onAddRow()">Add Row</button>
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid
    style="width: 850px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine custom-class"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [editType]="'fullRow'"
    [suppressClickEdit]="true"
    [domLayout]="domLayout"
    (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md float-right rounded-pill" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Apply</button>
```

table.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setFormData();
    this.getGridData();   
    this.getMacFilterData();
  }

  getGridData() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'MAC Address',
        field: 'DeviceMacAddress',
        cellStyle: { 'font-color': 'black', 'font-size': '11px' },
        resizable: true,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        width: 400,
        editable: true,
        colId: "action",
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        
          valueGetter: params => {
              return params.data.DeviceMacAddress;
          },
          valueSetter: params => {
              params.data.DeviceMacAddress = params.newValue;
              return true;
          }
      
      {
        headerName: 'Actions',
        cellRendererFramework: RemoveRendererComponent,
        editable: false,
        colId: "action",
        width: 450,
        cellStyle: { fontSize: '11px' }
      }
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
      rowData: null,
      enableFilter: true,
      onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
        console.log("grid-event", event)
        const gridData = this.getMacFilterData();
      }
    };

  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    
  }
  getMacFilterData() {
   return this.http.get('assets/json/mac.json').subscribe((data:any)=>{
  console.log("data", data)
  this.macStatusValue= data
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
this.settings.updateEnabledDisabledString(this.macFilterFormGroup.value.macStatus)
    let body = {
      "devicekey": this.deviceService.getDeviceKey(),
      "settings": {
        "wireless": {
          "wlanmacfilter": {
            "status": '',
            "blockeddevices": [
              this.macStatusValue.blockeddevices],
            "whitelist": [this.macStatusValue.whitelist]

          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("body", body)


    this.macFilterService.updateWlanMacSettings(body).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        alert("Successfully Updated WlanMac Filter Settings")
        this.getMacFilterData();
      } else {
        alert('Something went wrong, please try again')
      }
    });
  }

  onAddRow()
  {
    this.agGrid.api.updateRowData({
 add: [{}],

    });
    console.log("length", this.rowData.length)

  }
  onCellValueChanged(params) {
    const colId = params.column.getId();
    console.log("colId", colId)
}


[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps using the row value changed event:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-editing-rowValueChanged

Use it in your HTML file with `(rowValueChanged)="onRowValueChanged($event)"`